# How to make compilation in emacs through ALT-M?

Tags: emacs, compilation

The compilation process is very mute in emacs and that's why I decided to make it faster and more convenient, and I only got the problem that this program (strings of code) is not self-updating, that is, `compile-command` (after first launching), stay the same and will not change without intervention, and I decided to add on `defin`, but my ignorance in lisp stopped me, the result was unsuccessful.

**Question:** How to make my function work correctly so that with every new ALT-M click `compile-command` is new.

What I tried to do:

```
(defun x-recompile (compile-command)
(setq compile-command '(concat "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.3.0/bin/gcc-8 -O2 -Wall -o "
                   (if (file-name-sans-extension buffer-file-name)
                  (shell-quote-argument
                   (file-name-sans-extension buffer-file-name)))
                   " "
                    (if buffer-file-name
                    (shell-quote-argument (buffer-file-name))))))

(define-key global-map "\eM" 'compile)
(define-key global-map "\em" 'x-recompile)
```

Initial version:

```
(setq compile-command '(concat "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.3.0/bin/gcc-8 -O2 -Wall -o "
                   (if (file-name-sans-extension buffer-file-name)
                  (shell-quote-argument
                   (file-name-sans-extension buffer-file-name)))
                   " "
                    (if buffer-file-name
                    (shell-quote-argument (buffer-file-name)))))
(define-key global-map "\eM" 'compile)
(define-key global-map "\em" 'recompile)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way to accomplish this is to use a mode hook:

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (set (make-local-variable 'compile-command)
         (concat "/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.3.0/bin/gcc-8 -O2 -Wall -o "
                 (if (file-name-sans-extension buffer-file-name)
                     (shell-quote-argument
                      (file-name-sans-extension buffer-file-name)))
                 " "
                 (if buffer-file-name
                     (shell-quote-argument (buffer-file-name)))))))
```

This will set `compile-command` when you visit the file and then `compile` and `recompile` will work appropriately.

1. Add the above code to `.emacs`
2. Evaluate the form
3. Re-visit the file (kill the buffer and open the file again)
4. <kbd>C-h v compile-command RET</kbd> to see the value
5. <kbd>M-x compile RET</kbd> or whatever you bind `compile` to

Comment: Please see the instructions

Comment: I really tried very hard, I removed all strings with a compile ... nothing works, make -k instead of my command, whether there is a workaround?

Comment: Put the code in `.emacs`, restart emacs, report here the value of `c-mode-hook`. Open your C file. Report the value of `compile-command` here (as reported by `C-h v compile-command RET`.

Comment: you need to evaluate the code using `C-x C-e` and then it will work even in an existing emacs, *BUT* only for new buffers, or you can do `M-x fundamental-mode RET M-x c-mode RET` in an existing buffer to trigger `c-mode-hook`.

Comment: n.b. `M-x c-mode` will trigger its hook even when the buffer was already in `c-mode`.  No need to change to another mode first.  In general `M-x normal-mode` can be used.

Comment: ...or you might revert (marked) buffers en masse from `M-x ibuffer`, which is quick to do.